# Create multiple HTML elements in for-loop from array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create some HTML Elements of the same type with a for loop in JavaScript.
I wonder if I need to create a new Javascript variable for every element I want to show in the DOM or is it enought to override the same element again and again in my loop?

I wrote this code but it does only show one element as output:

```
let i;    
for( i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
            let tabElement = document.createElement("div");
            tabElement.className = "tabElement";
            tabElement.className = "ellipsis";
            tabElement.id = "tabElement" + i;
            tabElement.innerHTML = events[i].name;
            
            let tabElementLink = document.createElement("a");
            tabElementLink.className = "tabElementLink";
            tabElementLink.id = "tabElementLink" + i;
            
            $("tabElementLink").append(tabElement);
            $(".tabBar").append(tabElementLink);
        }
```

Than I wrote the following code but it this applies the same innerHTML to all returned elements.

```
let tabElements = {};
    let tabElementsLink = {};
    let i;
    for( i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
        tabElements['tabElement' + i] = document.createElement("div");
        tabElements['tabElement' + i].className = "tabElement";
        tabElements['tabElement' + i].className = "ellipsis";
        tabElements['tabElement' + i].id = "tabElement" + i;
        tabElements['tabElement' + i].innerHTML = events[i].name;
        
        tabElementsLink['tabElementLink' + i] = document.createElement("a");
        tabElementsLink['tabElementLink' + i].className = "tabElementLink";
        tabElementsLink['tabElementLink' + i].id = "tabElementLink" + i;
        tabElementsLink['tabElementLink' + i].append(tabElements['tabElement' + i]);
        $(".tabBar").append(tabElementsLink['tabElementLink' + i]);
        

    }
```

Which approach is right to generate multiple HTML elements from an array?

Comment: is `events.length` greater than 1?

Comment: The code in your question appears to work correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/1q6rLkv2/. A working example demonstrating the problem is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No metter, you can create every time new variable or rewrite. Better create variable every time.

your code can be optimized with new features and without any variables:

```js
const events = [
  {
    name: "event1"
  },
  {
    name: "event2"
  },
  {
    name: "event3"
  }
]

// if events is iterable 
events.forEach((event, index)=>{
   // for next lines, you forget href
  $(".tabBar").append(`<a href="link${index}" class="tabElementLink" id="tabElementLink${index}"><div class="tabsElement ellipsis" id="tabelement${index}">${event.name}</div></a>`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabBar"></div>
```

And i don't think that you need any id at all, better to use data-id or something